# iOS6 Putting Cursor in SPecific Text Field

Tags: ios, cursor, textinput

I have three text input fields that I clear after the user has added data to a database:

```
 self.textMonth.text  = @"";
 self.textTemp.text   = @"";
 self.textCloud.text  = @"";
```

How to I put the cursor in any one of those fields subsequently?

I have tried a number of the solutions provided elsewhere but none seem to work. Many thanks. EH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make your text field first responder using `becomeFirstResponder` like....

```
 [self.textMonth becomeFirstResponder];
```

to change textfield subsequently use `textFieldShouldReturn`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([self.textMonth isFirstReponder])
    {
        [self.textTemp becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if([self.textTemp isFirstReponder])
    {
        [self. textCloud becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if([self.textCloud isFirstReponder])
    {
        [self.textMonth becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it will help to solve your problem

Comment: to use `textFieldShouldReturn` method, do not forget to assign delegates

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
[self.textMonth becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on conditions you can use `becomeFirstResponder`

```
[self.textMonth becomeFirstResponder];
[self.textTemp becomeFirstResponder];
[self.textCloud becomeFirstResponder];
```